# Extract image data from camera roll on Android?

Tags: android-camera, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

Can anyone help me find out if/how you can get image data off of the 'camera roll' in an Android device, using (Appcelorator) Titanium ? I have found a 3rd party module for IOS that does this but I am desperate to find one for Android. Otherwise I'll have to scrap the Titanium and go true native.

What I need is a function that returns an array of data about the images on the device. Although I would love to get 'geolocation' data ( if it exists ), all I really need is a 'create date', and a path to the image, or the actual TiBlob.
Seems simple but i get no responses on the Appcelerator forums, which worries me. There must be at least an Android 'module' that achieves this?

Comment: Hi Jim i am creating a colour wheel and i need to extract the image data on the click image what module did you use for IOS? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
     allowEditing : true,
     success : function(event) {
     var image = require('/modules/parts/squarecropper').crop(event.media);
         setImage(image);
         Ti.Media.hideCamera();
     },
     cancel : function() {
     },
     saveToPhotoGallery : false,
     mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
});
```

The above method would do your job. Now then either access it directly or get into a file system and encode and decode the data.

```
    var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(currIamge);
    var temp = f.read();
    var encodeData = Ti.Utils.base64encode(temp);
    alert("encodeData = "+encodeData);
```